# What is the best way to give people your python program

Tags: python, linux, packaging

I want to give my python program to some people, and they will run this in Linux. What is the best way to do this ? Is it better to give them every script - I have 5 of them, or make it into an installer like *.deb

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

just tar (zip) it and send it off, .deb is debian based distro's only and tedious for just some scripts:

```
tar -pczf myscript.tar.gz /path/to/dir/with/scripts
```

for a bonus add a requirements.txt with the required external dependancies if you have external dependancies; this way people can install the requirements easily by running `pip install -r requirements.txt`; Example requirements.txt (one rule per required dep):

```
PIL==1.1.7
django==1.3.0
python-cjson
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have used `virtualenv` and `pip`, you can use `pip freeze` as described [here](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/05/notes-using-pip-and-virtualenv-django/).

In the installation instructions you tell your friend to use:

```
pip install -E foo -r foo/pip-requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know a little of C/C++, you could make a tiny C/C++ program which kinda Glues all your python scripts together and packs the Python interpreter with it making a pretty presentable executable. Google "Embedding python scripts into a C/C++ application" and look for the CPython Api reference in your python docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a .deb package with:

```
fakeroot dpkg-deb --build /yourdirectory
```

Your directory should have a yourdirectory/DEBIAN/control file as described [here](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html), and yourdirectory/usr/share/uniquename for your program's files, and whatever other directories that need to be installed.